# Create dynamic email addresses to forward messages and replies

Tags: email, architecture, smtp, messaging

I have a situation where we have users who would like to message a different user type, let's call them client and provider.

We don't want to set up a whole messaging system because not all providers will be using our infrastructure.

Therefore we would like to implement the following flow:

1. Client clicks 'email provider'
2. native email client opens up with a dynamically created email address such as 'message-provider1234@ouraddress.com'
3. Client sends an email to this address
4. Our system forwards this email to the provider's real email address
5. Provider replies back to our email
6. We forward this email to the original sender (client)

Does anybody know if there are any exisitng solutions to this? Or guidance as to how we might go about implementing?